# PyQt5 QWebEngineView not working properly

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

This code doesn't show anything on execution. Not even the main window.
How can I use QWebEngineView() in order to make a useful code.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setWindowTitle('Browser Lite')
        self.setGeometry(5, 30, 1355, 730)


        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.load(QUrl('http://www.google.com'))

        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = MainWindow()
win.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Works fine for me. How are you running the script, and on what platform? Do you see any errors?

Comment: I am having this same exact issue. Are there any updates on this?

Answer (score -1):

If you mean you get a blank screen try adding the following

```
from OpenGL import GL # apt install python3-opengl ..will get blank screen and console spam "shader program is not linked"
```

For a full example you could take a look at the following [simplebrowser/pyqt5](https://github.com/shaolo1/qtwebengine/tree/dev/examples/webenginewidgets/simplebrowser/pyqt5)